# Inability to access in remote server

Tags: php

A little help brothers. I recently completed a project using localhost as my host.. It worked perfectly but when I hosted it I get a lot of errors starting from the index and after changing the root_path which I define in my config.php

// To access the DIRECTORY path

```
define("BASE_URL","/fiverr_pen247/");




define("ROOT_PATH",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/fiverr_pen247/");




define("HOST", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

I changed it to

// To access the DIRECTORY path

```
define("BASE_URL","/fiverr_pen247/");




define("ROOT_PATH",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/");




define("HOST", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

But I get errors when I click on register which I included in the page

This is error I get

Not Found

The requested URL /register was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This is my where I included the header in index.php

```
require("includes/config.php");
```

include(ROOT_PATH."includes/header.php");

```
<section id="hero-banner">
```

This is my register.php

require('includes/config.php'); 
    require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'core/class.user.php');

```
$user = new USER();

if($user->is_loggedin()!=""){
    $user->redirect(BASE_URL.'user');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my htaccess code

RewriteEngine On

## ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/404

## Adds www prefix

## RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.

## RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /fiverr_pen247/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]

{3,}\s([^.]+).php [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: But I don't know if Url Rewriting is enabled in the remote server that I want to host it in